# Expression for last non Null Value or Null Value in Database Table Column with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Database Table that looks like this:

```
Date             Type
2020-01-01       non_empty_date
2020-01-02       non_empty_date
1900-01-01       with_1900
2020-01-03       nom_empty_date
NULL             
NULL
```

The expected output is something like this:

```
Date             Type
2020-01-01       non_empty_date
2020-01-02       non_empty_date
1900-01-01       with_1900
2020-01-03       non_empty_date
NULL             Null_comes_After_non_empty_date
NULL             Null_comes_After_empty_date
```

logic is like this:

1. If there is date column isn't empty give Type non_empty_date
2. Exception: If the date column is 1900-01-01 give with_1900
3. If the date column is Null and comes after non empty date give 'Null_Comes_After_non_empty_date'
4. If the date column is Null and comes after empty date give 'Null_Comes_After_empty_date'

What I have tried so far to define Type is this in an Expression builder:

```
case (
Date == toDate(toString('1900-01-01')),'with_1900',
!isNull(Date), 'non_empty_date'
)
```

I am just confused, what expression should be written to give value for 3) and 4).

Any help or any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can we add loop  row numbers to these rows and generate new columns based on the row numbers? Or these rows are irregular, so we can't do this.

Comment: First of all Joseph, thank you so much for the answer. The rows are irregular. It can be anything. But I appreciate any solutions way :) Please let me know what you thought about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is based on values from the previous row. To do that, use a Window transformation that is set to look back at the previous row values using Range by 1 row behind.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Mark! However, I am very new to ADF. Could you please give me concrete example or guide me to a literature where those examples can be found. Thank you again so much for your time.

Comment: Windows transformation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-window#range-by. Lead/Lag functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#lag